# Backup files from recovery utility

Tags: backup, recovery

My Mac seems to have given up.  I have my important data backed up, but I have a few gigs of movies and music that I wasn't backing up.   I can boot into the recovery utility and launch a terminal, and can `ls /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/joe/Documents` and see my data, but how can I launch finder (or anything else) to grab these files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few methods to accomplish this:

1. If you have another Mac accessible, boot the dying Mac into [Target Disk Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3838). Plug it into the other Mac via Thunderbolt or Firewire. You should see your dying Mac show up as an external hard drive. Drag and drop what is needed.
2. Get an external hard drive at least the size of your Mac's internal drive. Plug it in and boot into Recovery Mode. Open Disk Utility. You should see the external drive and boot volume. Use Disk Utility to [Restore](http://macs.about.com/od/backupsarchives/ss/diskbackup_4.htm) one volume to the other. This will destroy any existing data on the external hard drive.
3. If you can't reformat an external hard drive but have a bit of space available to move the select files you need, you can boot into Recovery Mode and use Terminal to move the files over that you need. Use the [cp](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html) UNIX command to do this. For example, to move all of your Documents to an external hard drive named "External" you would use the following command:

   `cp -r "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/joe/Documents/" "/Volumes/External/"`

Comment: I am having a problems with the following command: `cp -r "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/joe/Documents/" "/Volumes/External"`. When I try to copy the documents directory - it appears to go through each file in the directory - and then returns the message No such file or directory for each file. Can you explain what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if using the `cp -r "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/joe/Documents/" "/Volumes/External"` make sure to have the last slash at the end or it may have trouble finding the drive. it should be

```
cp -r "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/joe/Documents/" "/Volumes/External/"
```

also make sure your drive is actually named "External" as it is in the example above.