# Backup files in internet recovery mode: cp command errors

Tags: terminal, backup, command-line, recovery

I'm currently trying to backup files from my MacBook Pro (2011) to an external hard drive in internet recovery mode (my laptop has been stuck on the bootscreen for the past 2 days, I think the hard drive is failing).

In order to do so, I've been trying to use cp commands in the Terminal, but I keep receiving the error message "no such file or directory".
Here are the commands I've run (I used the information [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84398/backup-files-from-recovery-utility) to guide myself) :

`cp -r "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/myusername/Documents/" "/Volumes/nameofextHD/"`

`cp -r "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/myusername/Desktop/" "/Volumes/nameofextHD/"`

`cp -r "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/myusername/Pictures/"*.jpg "/Volumes/nameofextHD/"`

I'm wondering if anyone could help me fix these cp commands please?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It may be a permission issue, can you change directory to or list the contents of `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/myusername/Documents/` or `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/myusername/Desktop/`? Can you create a file in "/Volumes/nameofextHD/" with `touch "/Volumes/nameofextHD/testfile"`? You may need to change permissions with `chmod` (for example, `chmod -R "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/myusername/Desktop" a+r`).

Comment: In recovery, the user is root so there should be no issues with permissions. Have you checked that those directories exist.  What do you get for `ls /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/Username`?

Comment: What does lsshow for those paths?

Answer (score 0):

The error has to be in the names of the directory structures you use. For example, using the last command the error must be in the names

"/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/myusername/Pictures/"
or
"/Volumes/nameofextHD/"

There is a problem with one of these names or else there are no jpgs in that directory.

The same applies for the other statements. Did you mean to use the -r or the -R option with the copy command? My computer running High Sierra doesn't show a -r option for the cp command. I think you want -R.

Comment: RE: "Did you mean to use the -r or the -R option with the copy command? My computer running High Sierra doesn't show a -r option for the cp command." -- In older versions of `cp` the `-r` _option_ was the same a `-R`, however... from the `cp` _man page_ under **macOS High Sierra**: **COMPATIBILITY** Historic versions of the **cp** utility had a **-r** option. This implementation supports that option; however, its use is strongly discouraged, as it does not correctly copy special files, symbolic links, or fifo’s.